# .NET small class with many instances optimization scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, optimization

I have millions of instances of class Data, I seek optimization advise.

Is there a way to optimize it in any way - save memory for example by serializing it somehow, although it will hurt the retrieval speed which is important too. Maybe turning the class to struct - but it seems that the class is pretty large for struct.

Queries for this objects can take hundreds-millions of these objects at a time. They sit in a list and queried by DateTime. The results are aggregated in different ways, many calculation can be applied.

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public abstract class BaseData {}

[Serializable]
public class Data : BaseData {
    public byte     member1;
    public int      member2;
    public long     member3;
    public double   member4;
    public DateTime member5;
}
```

Comment: It looks like maybe you could use a database here...

Comment: this is not an option because too much code is already written and integrated in c#

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, while you did specify that you want to "optimize", you did not specify what the exact problem is you mean to tackle. So I cannot really give you more than general advice.

Serialization will not help you. Your `Data` objects are already stored as bytes in memory. Nor will turning it into a struct help. The difference between a struct and a class lies in their addressing and referencing behaviour, not in their memory footprint.

The only way I can think of to reduce the memory footprint of a collection with "hundreds-millions" of these objects would be to serialize *and compress* the entire thing. But that is not feasible. You would always have to decompress the entire thing before accessing it, which would shoot your performance to hell AND actually almost double the memory consumption on access (compressed and decompressed data both lying in memory at that point).

The best general advice I can give you is not to try to optimize this scenario yourself, but use specialized software for that. By specialized software, I mean a (in-memory) database. One example of a database you can use in-memory, and for which you already have everything you need on-board in the .NET framework, is [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

Answer (score 1):

I assume, as you seem to imply, that you have a class with many members, have a large number of instances, and need to keep them all in memory at the same time to perform calculations.

I ran a few tests to see if you could actually get different sizes for the classes you described.

I used this simple method for finding the in-memory size of an object:

```
private static void MeasureMemory()
{
    int size = 10000000;
    object[] array = new object[size];

    long before = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)            
    {
        array[i] = new Data();
    }
    long after = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

    double diff = after - before;

    Console.WriteLine("Total bytes: " + diff);
    Console.WriteLine("Bytes per object: " + diff / size);
}
```

It may be primitive, but I find that it works fine for situations like this.

As expected, almost nothing you can do to that class (turning it to a struct, removing the inheritance, or the method attributes) influences the memory being used by a single instance. As far as memory usage goes, they are all equivalent. However, do try to fiddle with your actual classes and run them through the given code.

The only way you could actually reduce the memory footprint of an instance would be to use smaller structures for keeping your data (int instead of long for example). If you have a large number of booleans, you could group them into a byte or integer, and have simple property wrappers to work with them (A boolean takes a byte of memory). These may be insignificant things in most situations, but for a hundred million objects, removing a boolean could make a difference of a hundred MB of memory. Also, be aware that the platform target you choose for your application can have an impact on the memory footprint of an object (x64 builds take up more memory then x86 ones).

Serializing the data is very unlikely to help. An in-memory database has it's upsides, especially if you are doing complex queries. However, it is unlikely to actually reduce the memory usage for your data. Unfortunately, there just aren't many ways to reduce the footprint of basic data types. At some point, you will just have to move to a file-based database.

However, here are some ideas. Please be aware that they are hacky, highly conditional, decrease the computation performance and will make the code harder to maintain.

1. It is often a case in large data structures that objects in different states will have only some properties filled, and the other will be set to null or a default value. If you can identify such groups of properties, perhaps you could move them to a sub-class, and have one reference that could be null instead of having several properties take up space. Then you only instantiate the sub-class once it is needed. You could write property wrappers that could hide this from the rest of the code. Have in mind that the worst case scenario here would have you keeping all the properties in memory, plus several object headers and pointers.
2. You could perhaps turn members that are likely to take a default value into binary representations, and then pack them into a byte array. You would know which byte positions represent which data member, and could write properties that could read them. Position the properties that are most likely to have a default value at the end of the byte array (a few longs that are often 0 for example). Then, when creating the object, adjust the byte array size to exclude the properties that have the default value, starting from the end of the list, until you hit the first member that has a non-default value. When the outside code requests a property, you can check if the byte array is large enough to hold that property, and if not, return the default value. This way, you could potentially save some space. Best case, you will have a null pointer to a byte array instead of several data members. Worst case, you will have full byte arrays taking as much space as the original data, plus some overhead for the array. The usefulness depends on the actual data, and assumes that you do relatively few writes, as the re-computation of the array will be expensive.

Hope any of this helps :)